# Conditional Statements only for particular record types in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table like:

```
________________________________________________________
|  ID   | ADDRESS_LINE1 | CITY   | STATE | ZIP  | TYPE |
________________________________________________________
| 12345 | abcd st       | city1  |   CA  | zip1 |   1  |
| 12345 | abcd st       | city1  |   CA  | zip1 |   2  |
| 12345 | efgh st       | city2  |   CA  | zip2 |   3  |
________________________________________________________
```

In this table, I need to check if the Type is either 1 or 3 and not 2.

**I need an output like**:

*For the table record specified*

```
_______________________________________________________________
|  ID   | RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS      | MAILING_ADDRESS          |
_______________________________________________________________
| 12345 | abcd st, city1, CA, zip1 | efgh st, city2, CA ,zip2 |
_______________________________________________________________
```

*In case if Type 1 is not present in the table*

```
_______________________________________________________________
|  ID   | RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS      | MAILING_ADDRESS          |
_______________________________________________________________
| 12345 |                          | efgh st, city2, CA ,zip2 |
_______________________________________________________________
```

*In case if Type 3 is not present in the table*

```
_______________________________________________________________
|  ID   | RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS      | MAILING_ADDRESS          |
_______________________________________________________________
| 12345 | abcd st, city1, CA, zip1 |                          |
_______________________________________________________________
```

*In case if both Type 1 and Type 3 are not present*

```
_______________________________________________________________
|  ID   | RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS      | MAILING_ADDRESS          |
_______________________________________________________________
| 12345 |                          |                          |
_______________________________________________________________
```

**What I was trying**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
    ADDRLINE1 || ',' || CITY || ',' || STATE || ',' || ZIP (CASE WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS, 
    ADDRLINE1 || ',' || CITY || ',' || STATE || ',' || ZIP (CASE WHEN TYPE = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAILING_ADDRESS 
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID =  12345;
```

This throws an error

> ORA-00904:ZIP: Invalid Identifier

I know I'm missing something. Please help to frame a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing separator between ZIP column an the rest of code

If the case content is another columns the you need  a comma for separate column ZIP for RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS and MAILING_ADDRESS

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
      ADDRLINE1 || ',' || CITY || ',' || STATE || ',' || ZIP, (CASE WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS, 
      ADDRLINE1 || ',' || CITY || ',' || STATE || ',' || ZIP,  (CASE WHEN TYPE = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAILING_ADDRESS 
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE ID =  12345;
```

If the case content is another columns to concat the you need   ||the you need  a comma for separate column ZIP for RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS and MAILING_ADDRESS

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
      ADDRLINE1 || ',' || CITY || ',' || STATE || ',' || ZIP || (CASE WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS, 
      ADDRLINE1 || ',' || CITY || ',' || STATE || ',' || ZIP ||  (CASE WHEN TYPE = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAILING_ADDRESS 
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE ID =  12345;
```

or

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
      ADDRLINE1 || ',' || CITY || ',' || STATE || ',' || ZIP || ',' || (CASE WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS, 
      ADDRLINE1 || ',' || CITY || ',' || STATE || ',' || ZIP || ',' || (CASE WHEN TYPE = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAILING_ADDRESS 
  FROM TABLE
  WHERE ID =  12345;
```

If you need  the seult on same row for two diffenrent row the you need a join on table two time oen for each address eg:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, 
    a.ADDRLINE1 || ',' || a.CITY || ',' || a.STATE || ',' || a.ZIP AS RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS, 
    b.ADDRLINE1 || ',' || b.CITY || ',' || b.STATE || ',' || b.ZIP  AS MAILING_ADDRESS 
FROM TABLE a 
INNER JOIN TABLE b ON a.ID = b.ID 
  AND a.TYPE = 1 
  AND b.TYPE = 3 
WHERE a.ID =  12345;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @scaisEdge. Please find my update on the question.

Comment: @Mike  . asnwer update for result on a single row  (modifed  only the fist query you can do the rest)

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge.